# How is the similarity calculated in Postgres pg_trgm module

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

Can somebody explain to me exactly how the similarity function is calculated in Postgres pg_trgm module.

e.g. `similarity('sage', 'message') = 0.3`

```
1) "  s"," sa",age,"ge ",sag
2) "  m"," me",age,ess,"ge ",mes,sag,ssa

n1: cardinality(1) = 5
n2: cardinality(2) = 8
nt: cardinality(1 intersect 2) = 3
```

I can't see how we get a formula from these 3 quantities which is equal to 0.3. I would have expected it to be based on a common string similarity metric (e.g. Dice-Sorensen)

i.e. `2*nt / (n1 + n2) = 6/13 = 0.46`

pg_trgm similarity score seems to be unusually low to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula can be found in `contrib/pg_trgm/trgm.h` (see the macro `CALCSML`) and is as follows:

```
nt / (n1 + n2 - nt)
```

In your case that is `3 / (5+8-3) = 0.3`.